# Move margintext in line with rest of text

Tags: formatting, latex

I was wondering how to bring the names of the places of work on the left side in one line with the job titles and the date. E.g. Praktikum Psychologie should be in line with Sonnhalde Grüningen. See compilable code below. I've tried vspace etc. but haven't had much luck. Same issue with Ausbildung (Education) as well.

```
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Classicthesis-Styled CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (22/2/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Alessandro Plasmati
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Purple}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Purple, linkcolor=Purple} % Set link colors

\usepackage{enumitem}% Use the enumitem package for lists - http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\setlist{nolistsep}


\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=1em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{#1}\hspace{0.1em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

\usepackage{adforn}
  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{censored}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Persönliche Daten}\vspace{0.5em} % Personal information heading

\datebox=1in
\NewEntry{\large{*}}{censored}{} % Birthplace and date

\datebox=1in
\NewEntry{e-mail}{\href{mailto:censored}{censored} % Email address

\datebox=1in
\NewEntry{telefon}{censored} % Phone number(s)

\datebox=1in
\NewEntry{adresse}{censored} % Address

\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal

%\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} % Goal heading, could be used for a quotation or short profile instead

%\Description{Improve my skills in creating and developing cutting edge projects. Find a way to apply scientific approaches in solving practical problems. }\vspace{2em} % Goal text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Experience
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Berufserfahrung}\vspace{1em}

\datebox=3.2in

\datebox=3.2in
\NewEntry{Praktikum Psychologie}{\textit{08.2022 -- 02.2023}}

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{\href{https://www.klinik-sonnhalde.ch/}{Sonnhalde}} \\ Grüningen.} \vspace{-2mm}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Pensum 40-60 \% 
    \item Psychotherapiegespräche im Einzelsetting
    \item Co-Leitung Sozialkompetenztraining
    \item Leitung Gruppe Achtsamkeit
    \item Begleitung Psychiater auf Visiten
    \item regelmässige Teilhabe an Supervisionen
\end{itemize}}

\datebox=3.2in
\NewEntry{Praxisassistentin}{\textit{06.2019 -- 06.2022}}

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{Zentrum für Chiropraktik} \\ Zürich.} \vspace{-2mm}
}

\vspace{2.25em} % Extra space between major sections

\datebox=3.2in
\NewEntry{Praktikum Psychologie}{\textit{10.2020 -- 01.2021}}

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{\href{https://www.forio.ch/}{forio AG}} \\ Frauenfeld.} \vspace{-4mm}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Mitarbeit Begutachtungen und Testberichte
    \item selbstständige Durchführung psychodiagnostischer Testverfahren \\(\textsc{WISC-V}, \textsc{WAIS-IV}) mit Jugendlichen und Erwachsenen
\end{itemize}}

\datebox=3.2in
\NewEntry{Mitarbeiterin Hotellerie}{\textit{09.2016 -- 09.2019}}

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{Privatklinik Hirslanden} \\ Zürich.} \vspace{-4mm}
}


\vspace{2.25em} % Extra space between major sections


\datebox=3.2in
\NewEntry{Diverse Praktika}{\textit{07.2015--08.2016}}

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{} \\ } \vspace{-4mm}
}

\vspace{0.4em} % Extra space between major sections


------------


\vspace{0.4em} % Extra space between major sections

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Ausbildung}\vspace{1em}

\datebox=3.2in
\NewEntry{MSc Psychologie}{\textit{2020-2022}}

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{UZH} \\ Zürich.}
\vspace{-4mm}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Masterarbeit \\ \textit{Englisch als Lingua Franca und Machine Translation}
\end{itemize}}

\datebox=3.2in
\NewEntry{BSc Psychologie}{\textit{2016-2020}}

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{UZH} \\ Zürich.}
\vspace{-4mm}

}
\datebox=3.2in
\NewEntry{Gymnasiale Maturität}{\textit{2009-2015}}

\Description{\MarginText{\textsc{Kantonsschule} \\ Wetzikon.} 
\vspace{-4mm}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Schwerpunktfach Spanisch
\end{itemize}
}


%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OTHER INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1em} % Extra space between major sections

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Verschiedenes}\vspace{1em}

\Description{seit 2017 \ \ ~ $\cdotp$\ \ Vorstand Samariterverein Grüningen}

\vspace{-0.5em} % Negative vertical space to counteract the vertical space between every \Description command

\Description{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Mitglied Verein \href{https://www.njira.org/}{Njira}}


\vspace{-0.5em} % Negative vertical space to counteract the vertical space between every \Description command

\newpage
%------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\spacedlowsmallcaps{Software}\vspace{1em}

\Description{\MarginText{Ausgezeichnet}Microsoft Office Word \& Excel}

\Description{\MarginText{Fortgeschritten} R, \LaTeX, SDL Trados Studio, Adobe Illustrator \& InDesign}

%------------------------------------------------


\vspace{0.8em}
\spacedlowsmallcaps{Sonstiges}\vspace{1em}

\newlength{\langbox} % Create a new length for the length of languages to keep them equally spaced
\settowidth{\langbox}{Französisch} % Length equals the length of "English" - if you have a longer language in your list put it here

\Description{\MarginText{Sprachen}\parbox{\langbox}{\textsc{Deutsch}}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ Muttersprache}

\vspace{-0.5em} % Negative vertical space to counteract the vertical space between every \Description command

\Description{\parbox{\langbox}{\textsc{Englisch}}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ Muttersprache}

\vspace{-0.5em} % Negative vertical space to counteract the vertical space between every \Description command

\Description{\parbox{\langbox}{\textsc{Französisch}}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ B1}

\vspace{-0.5em} % Negative vertical space to counteract the vertical space between every \Description command

\Description{\parbox{\langbox}{\textsc{Russisch}}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \ A2}

\vspace{1em} % Negative vertical space to counteract the vertical space between every \Description command

%------------------------------------------------

\Description{\MarginText{Interessen}Fussball\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Schwimmen \ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Sprache \& Geschichte \ \ $\cdotp$\ \ Typografie \& Drucksatz}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does *not* compile. `File ended while scanning use of \NewEntry.`